# How to merge columns based on its values - pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I've a table like this:

```
    c0 | c1 | c2 | c3
________________________
    1  | 2  |NaN | NaN
    3  | 4  |NaN | NaN
   NaN |NaN |5   | 6
   NaN |NaN |28  | 3
```

And now I want to merge them, to get only to columns with the non NaN values as:

```
    c0 | c1 |
_______________
    1  | 2  |
    3  | 4  |
    5  | 6  |
   28  | 3  |
```

Is there any function that do this in Pandas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use combine_first()

```
df['c0'] = df.c0.combine_first(df.c2)
df['c1'] = df.c1.combine_first(df.c3)
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `apply`

```
df.apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.isnull),1).dropna(1)
Out[458]: 
     c0   c1
0   1.0  2.0
1   3.0  4.0
2   5.0  6.0
3  28.0  3.0
```

Comment: great answer btw :)

Comment: @sooaran yep :-)

Comment: @sooaran if this is what you need can you consider accept it?